# Filter from two textviews in regular listview

Tags: android, listview, filter, simplecursoradapter, addtextchangedlistener

I have a regular listview with **SimpleCursorAdapter** and two textviews and I want to filter against only one of my textview

How can I do this?

```
   EditText e ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_activity);

    e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

    DataBaseH data = new DataBaseH(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = data.getReadableDatabase();
    String ret = "";

    Cursor C = db.rawQuery("select * from Album ", null);

    final SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, C, new String[]{"Title", "country"}, new int[]{R.id.t, R.id.t2}, 0);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    e.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

            // this doesn't work 
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Just want to filter on the title.

Can I filter on both title and country?

Comment: Yes you can filter title and country.

Comment: setup `FilterQueryProvider` in your adapter

Comment: @SagarZala how can I do this

Comment: As pskink says, you have to use *setFilterQueryProvider()*